# when use function the_content break

Tags: filters

i use the function below to show content under the_content. It works on pages which uses template-test.php. But on other pages the_content stops output.

```
function beschreibung_kriterien( $content ) {

    if ( is_page_template( 'template-test.php' ) ) {

        $content .= '<h2>Test</h2>';

        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'beschreibung_kriterien', 5 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you only return `$content` from inside your `if` - you should *always* return it:

```
function beschreibung_kriterien( $content ) {
    if ( is_page_template( 'template-test.php' ) ) {
         $content .= '<h2>Test</h2>';
    }

    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'beschreibung_kriterien', 5 );
```

This just goes to the show the importance of proper indentation!